# create a custom navbar that can handle push actions

Tags: ios

I want to do something like this (custom buttons in a topbar):

[image]

Currently i've just implemented my custom view with buttons.
But now I need to add support of pushing new controllers clicking these buttons ->
and here I've faced:

```
Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

Is it possible to create a custom navbar that can handle push actions?

Comment: Are you using storyboards?  In xcode if you use story boards you can hold control and click and drag from a button to a view controller and have it push or modal to that view controller.

Comment: yes, but I can easily move to nibs

Comment: Would you be willing to send me your project.  I don't really understand what you have and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xcode hold `CTRL` and drag from the button to the other view controller and click `modal` on the drop down.

Comment: only if you use UINavigationController

Comment: just opened for myself modal actions:)